# How do I upload 2 separate variables into the Firebase database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to upload 2 variables into my Firebase database. The 1st variable is the only one been uploaded. Variable newRoute is being uploaded but new User isn't. I have the whole web app's Fire configuration set up so that isn't a problem.

```
$("#add-route-btn").on("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var pickUp = $("#pickUp-input").val().trim();
  var destination = $("#destination-input").val().trim();
  var time = moment($("#time-input").val().trim(), "hh:mm").format("hh:mm");  

  var newRoute = {
    pickup: pickUp,
    destination: destination,
    time: time
  };

  database.ref().push(newRoute);

  alert("Route successfully added");

  $("#pickUp-input").val("");
  $("#destination-input").val("");
  $("#time-input").val("");
});

$("#add-newUser-btn").on("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();


  var newName = $("#name-input").val().trim();
  var passengers = $("#passengers-input").val().trim();

  var newUser = {
    name: newName,
    passengers: passengers
  };

  database.ref().push(newUser);


  alert("New Passengers successfully added");

  $("#name-input").val("");
  $("#passengers-input").val("");
});

database.ref().on("child_added", function (childSnapshot) {

  var pickUp = childSnapshot.val().pickup;
  var destination = childSnapshot.val().destination;
  var time = childSnapshot.val().time;

  var newName = childSnapshot.val().name;
  var passengers = childSnapshot.val().passengers;
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console ?

Comment: No errors. It just shows the variables newName and passengers as undefined when I try to add them. I have console.logged most of the variables but I didn't include it here since it was to long to post.

Comment: Is your by-id selectors correct ?

Comment: Yes, they are correct. I think I fixed it. It was actually an error in the HTML file, I had the ID for on of the buttons written likes this: id="#add-newUser-btn". Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Well, actually. It is uploading but to the same section as the first variable. I want them to upload in different variables

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get data with `child_added` on a single ref `database.ref().on("child_added"....` seems like you're trying to push both data to same location as well...

I suggest you should have one `ref` to `routes` and another one to `passengers`:

```
let routesRef = firebase.database().ref('/routes');
let passengersRef = firebase.database().ref('/passengers');

// push to Route
routesRef.push(routeDataHere);

// push to Passenger
passengerRef.push(passengerDataHere);

// listen to added Route
routesRef.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
  let data = snapshot.val();
  let pickup = data.pickup;
  let destination = data.destination;
  let time = data.time
});

// listen to added Passenger
passengerRef.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
  let data = snapshot.val();
  let name = data.name;
  let passengers = data.passengers;
});
```

Check out more details at the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)